# node - how to read correctly json from a local file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, vis.js

I am using node.js to serve a page (index.html) where I visualize a network graph,  using [vis.js](http://visjs.org/). In order to draw a network graph with this library, one needs to provide a **nodes** and **edges** json arrays ([see example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html)).

```
// create an array with nodes
  var _nodes_ = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
  ];


  // create an array with edges
  var _edges_ = [
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5}
  ];
```

The first version of my **index.html** file looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network | Basic usage</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vis.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" >


  // create an array with nodes    
  var _nodes_ = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
  ];


  // create an array with edges
  var _edges_ = [
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5}
  ];

console.log(_nodes_);
console.log(_edges_);


  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data= {
    nodes: _nodes_,
    edges: _edges_,
  };
  var options = {
    autoResize: true,
    clickToUse: false,
    width: '800px',
    height: '800px'
  };
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And it is working just fine. However, when I try to read from a local file the **nodes** and **edges** arrays, the network graph doesn't show up:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network | Basic usage</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vis.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
  // create an array with nodes

var _nodes_;
var _edges_;

 $.getJSON('json/nodes.json', function(nodes) {
     _nodes_= nodes;
  });

  $.getJSON('json/edges.json', function(edges) {
      _edges_ = edges;

  });



console.log(_nodes_);
console.log(_edges_);


  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data= {
    nodes: _nodes_,
    edges: _edges_,
  };
  var options = {
    autoResize: true,
    clickToUse: false,
    width: '800px',
    height: '800px'
  };
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using:

- **nodes.json**:

  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "Node 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "Node 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "Node 3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "label": "Node 4"
    }
  ]
- **edges.json**:

  [
    {
      "from": 1,
      "to": 2
    },
    {
      "from": 1,
      "to": 3
    },
    {
      "from": 1,
      "to": 4
    }
  ]

Is there a difference between creating a json inside your javascript and reading from  a file? Can someone help me spot the error here please?

Thanks!

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous function. You execute your logic and `console.log` values before they even retrieved.

Comment: @anvk That was helpful, thanks! I got i now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous by default so you have to draw the graph after your data is loaded!

Or you could use the `add` function of `DataSet` to add your nodes and edges after they are loaded.

Here is an working example:

```js
var _nodes = new vis.DataSet();
var _edges = new vis.DataSet();

var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
  nodes: _nodes,
  edges: _edges,
};
var options = {
  autoResize: true,
  clickToUse: false
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

$.getJSON('//gist.githubusercontent.com/mojoaxel/b9ed2fe1ff7154b339d6ffde555f0606/raw/6d9b1c4e0b642ab05837ee60a6c6ca9f64b9995f/edges.json', function(edges) {
  _edges.add(edges);
});
$.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mojoaxel/b9ed2fe1ff7154b339d6ffde555f0606/raw/6d9b1c4e0b642ab05837ee60a6c6ca9f64b9995f/nodes.json', function(nodes) {
 _nodes.add(nodes);
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of @anvk, I set the global ajax configs to synchronous by doing `$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });` before my `$.getJSON` and It worked! I can toggle them back to asynchronous by `$.ajaxSetup({ async: true });`

Thanks.

Comment: I hope it is what I want. Asynchronous execution is much faster than async since you can read 2 separate file in parallel and execute your logic once those 2 actions are complete. I would highly recommend you to read more about async functions and flow in JavaScript

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. For now, this is what I want, I have 2 objects that I need to read from 2 separate files. So I don't think async or sync would make a big difference in this case. But still, you're right and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format `{"id": "1", "label": "Node 1"}` for nodes.json.

Use `'source'&'target'` instead of `'from' & 'to'` for edges.json.

Here is the example of vis.js . Please check the JSON file format in this example.http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/importingFromGephi.html